# Indirection requires pointer when multiplying with flex in C

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I've been trying to solve this from the past 3 hours and after solving other problems, I get another problems.

Suppose I have a flex file named "main.c":

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t WAV_BPM = 120;
uint64_t WAV_ALLOC = 0;
uint32_t WAV_SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
#define WAV_BPM_PERIOD (double) 60*WAV_SAMPLE_RATE/WAV_BPM;
%}

%%
"NOTE_1" {WAV_ALLOC += WAV_BPM_PERIOD*4;}
"NOTE_2" {WAV_ALLOC += WAV_BPM_PERIOD*2;}
"NOTE_4" {WAV_ALLOC += WAV_BPM_PERIOD;}
"NOTE_8" {WAV_ALLOC += (uint64_t) WAV_BPM_PERIOD/2.0;}
.        {printf("unknown character %s\n", yytext);}
%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  return 0;
}
```

After I tried executing this with `flex -o mainlex.c main.c && gcc -lfl mainlex.c`, I get an error from gcc:

```
main.c:11:29: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
{WAV_ALLOC += WAV_BPM_PERIOD*4;}
                            ^~
...
```

How did this happen? I'm not dealing with pointers, I'm just multiplying variables. And when I replaced `#define WAV_BPM_PERIOD (double) 60*WAV_SAMPLE_RATE/WAV_BPM;` to`double WAV_BPM_PERIOD = (double) 60*WAV_SAMPLE_RATE/WAV_BPM;`, gcc gives me an another problem:

```
main.c:7:52: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
double WAV_BPM_PERIOD = (double) 60*WAV_SAMPLE_RATE/WAV_BPM;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How did this happen?

Sloppy macros. You have a stray semicolon so the compiler sees `(double) 60*WAV_SAMPLE_RATE/WAV_BPM;*4`. A proper macro would have been written as:

```
#define WAV_BPM_PERIOD (60.0*WAV_SAMPLE_RATE/WAV_BPM)
```

---

> error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant

What it says, the initializer is not a compile-time constant. This is FAQ, you can't initialize file scope variables ("globals") with other variables, since a variable is neither resolved at compile-time, nor an integer constant expression. You could solve this by changing the declaration of `WAV_SAMPLE_RATE` etc into `#define WAV_SAMPLE_RATE 44100` instead of a variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that I always forget when to put colon in C. Now it became a habit everywhere. dang I losed 3 hours of time just because of a semicolon.

Comment: @Spade000 This is an initiation ritual we force all new C programmers to go through =) First they suffer from missing semicolons for a long while, then they suffer from accidental semicolons in statements and macros. And compilers by tradition strive to give as unhelpful messages as possible when there's missing semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

its because of the semicolon after your #define:

```
#define WAV_BPM_PERIOD (double) 60*WAV_SAMPLE_RATE/WAV_BPM;
```

when the compiler inserts that into the code, it will look like:

```
#define WAV_BPM_PERIOD (double) 60*WAV_SAMPLE_RATE/WAV_BPM;*4;
```

A macro is a literal copy and paste into your code before compilation and always should be treated as such.

You should either just remove the semicolon or put your define in brackets then remove the semicolon, depending on what you're trying to do.

```
#define WAV_BPM_PERIOD (double) 60*WAV_SAMPLE_RATE/WAV_BPM
```

or

```
#define WAV_BPM_PERIOD (double) (60*WAV_SAMPLE_RATE/WAV_BPM)
```